# $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a normal linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra

I did an undergrad in mathematics but I've been working in the financial sector for a few years and it seems my math skills have all but deteriorated... I'm going problems in my old linear algebra textbook for fun and I've been trying to figure out these three factoids for awhile now... Would appreciate some help, thanks

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a normal linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space. I'm trying to understand why the following things are true:

$(i):$ $||T(x)|| = ||T^*(x)||$ for all $x \in V$

$(ii):$ If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T$ with corresponding eigenvector $x$, then $T^*(x) = \bar{\lambda}x$, where $\bar{\lambda}$ is the complex conjugate of $\lambda$.

$(iii):$ If $\lambda,\mu$ are distinct eigenvalues, with corresponding eigenvectors $x,y$, then $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$

---

My thoughts:

$(i)$: I was thinking that this should be true, since the $^*$ just takes the transpose and the conjugate, so the norm should remain the same... Would obviously like to understand this deeper though.

$(ii):$ Seems obvious but I don't know how to show it...

$(iii)$ I have no clue

If somebody could help me out with this and provide some details that'd be great, my math skills arn't what they used to be...

Comment: Might help to know that a $A$ is normal **iff** it is unitarily diagonalisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\|Tv\|^2 = \langle Tv, Tv \rangle = \langle v, T^* T v \rangle$. Now use the fact that $T$ is normal to show that the right-hand side equals $\|T^* v\|^2$.
- Show that $T-\lambda I$ is also normal (note that its conjugate transpose is $T^* - \bar{\lambda} I$). Then note $0=\|(T-\lambda I) x\|^2$ and use the result in (i).
- $\bar{\lambda} \langle x, y \rangle = \langle \lambda x, y \rangle = \langle Tx, y\rangle = \langle x, T^* y \rangle = \langle x, \bar{\mu} y \rangle = \bar{\mu} \langle x, y \rangle$, where we have used the result in (ii).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question though. For the third answer, why is the first equality as it is? In particular, why when you move the $\lambda$ inside of the inner product do you take it's conjugate?

Comment: @FireFenix777 If you write things using the conjugate transpose, it would be $(\lambda x)^* y = \lambda^* x^* y$, and note that $\lambda^* = \bar{\lambda}$. More generally, [inner products on complex vector spaces are conjugate linear in one of the arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Elementary_properties) and linear in the other (the choice of which argument is conjugate linear is a matter of convention).

Answer (score 1):

You write about conjugate transposes, but on an abstract inner product space there is no such thing as a "transpose" since linear maps are not matrices.  At least I would not speak of a "conjugate transpose". I'd speak of an adjoint: $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$.

The most important condition to use here is how a linear operator interacts with the inner product: $\boxed{\langle Tv,w\rangle = \langle v,T^*w\rangle}$ for all $v, w \in V$. This formula, quantified over all $v$ and $w$ in $V$, is how you *define* the mapping $T^* \colon V \to V$. That is, for each $w \in V$, the function $\mathbf C^n \to \mathbf C$ given by $v \mapsto \langle Tv,w\rangle$ is $\mathbf C$-linear and therefore it must be pairing against a specific vector in $V$ that we define to be $T^*w$:  $\langle Tv,w\rangle =  \langle v,T^*w\rangle$ for all $v \in V$.

In the *special case* $V = \mathbf C^n$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbf C^n$ such that $\langle \sum z_je_j,\sum w_je_j\rangle = \sum z_j\overline{w_j}$ for standard basis $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ of $\mathbf C^n$, you can check that
$$
\langle M(\mathbf v),\mathbf w\rangle = \langle \mathbf v,\overline{M}^\top(\mathbf w)\rangle
$$
for all $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ in $\mathbf C^n$, so $M^* = \overline{M}^\top$. This *motivates* the definition of $T^*$ in the abstract case, but you can't say in some abstract setting that $T^*$ is a "transpose" since abstract $T$'s are not matrices.

*Proof of (i)*.  Express the norm on $V$ in terms of the inner product by squaring:
$$
||Tv||^2 = \langle Tv,Tv\rangle = \langle v,T^*(Tv)\rangle = 
\langle v,T(T^*v)\rangle = \langle T^*v,T^*v\rangle = ||T^*v||^2.
$$
Thus $||Tv|| = ||T^*v||$.

*Proof of (ii)*. First I'll show a property of all linear operators $T : V \to V$, not just normal ones: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*$.  From $Tv = \lambda v$, where $v \not= 0$ in $V$, we get for all $w \in V$ that
$$
\langle Tv,w\rangle = \langle v,T^*w\rangle \Longrightarrow 
\langle \lambda v,w\rangle = \langle v,T^*w\rangle \Longrightarrow \lambda\langle v,w\rangle = \langle v,T^*w\rangle.
$$
We can put $\lambda$ back into the inner product on the right side using its complex conjugate:
$$
\langle v,\overline{\lambda}w\rangle = \langle v,T^*w\rangle \Longrightarrow \langle v,(T^* - \overline{\lambda}I)w\rangle = 0.
$$
Here $v$ is a nonzero element of $V$ and that vanishing of the inner product is true for *all* $w \in V$. That means the subspace
${\rm im}(T^* - \overline{\lambda}I) = \{(T^* - \overline{\lambda} I)w : w \in V\}$ can't be all of $V$ (we certainly can't have $v$ in the image, since $v$ isn't $0$!), so $T^* - \overline{\lambda}I$ is not surjective. Therefore (since $V$ is finite-dimensional) $T^* - \overline{\lambda} I$ is not injective, so there is a nonzero $w \in V$ such that $(T^* - \overline{\lambda} I)(w) = 0$, which makes $T^*w = \overline{\lambda}w$.  We have shown that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an arbitrary linear operator $T \colon V \to V$, then $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^* \colon V \to V$. This is not going to be used in the proof of (ii), but it may be helpful to compare such reasoning to what I now do to prove (ii).

Suppose $T$ is normal and $Tv = \lambda v$. We want to show $T^*v = \overline{v}$. Since $Tv - \lambda v = 0$,
$$
0 = \langle Tv - \lambda v,Tv - \lambda v\rangle = 
\langle (T - \lambda I)v,(T - \lambda I)v\rangle = 
\langle v,(T-\lambda I)^*(T-\lambda I)v\rangle.
$$
Since $(T - \lambda I)^* = T^* - (\lambda I)^* = T^* - \overline{\lambda}I$,
$$
0 = \langle v,(T^*- \overline{\lambda} I)(T-\lambda I)v\rangle.
$$
Since $T$ and $T^*$ commute, while *all* linear operators commute with scaling, $T^* - \overline{\lambda}I$ and $T - \lambda I$ commute. Thus
$$
0 = \langle v,(T - \lambda I)(T^*- \overline{\lambda} I)v\rangle = 
\langle (T - \lambda I)^*v,(T^* - \overline{\lambda}I)v\rangle = 
\langle (T^* - \overline{\lambda} I)v,(T^* - \overline{\lambda}I)v\rangle.
$$
Therefore $(T^* - \overline{\lambda})v = 0$, so $T^*v = \overline{\lambda}v$.  If $v \not= 0$ then $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and we showed it is also an eigenvector of $T^*$ with eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$>

*Proof of (iii)*.  Suppose $Tv = \lambda v$ and $Tw = \mu w$. Then
$$
\lambda \langle v,w\rangle = \langle \lambda v,w\rangle = 
\langle Tv,w\rangle = \langle v,T^*w\rangle.
$$
Since $T$ is normal, by (ii) we have $T^*w = \overline{\mu} w$. Thus
$$
\lambda \langle v,w\rangle = \langle v,\overline{\mu}w\rangle = 
\mu\langle v,w\rangle.
$$
Therefore the complex number $\langle v,w\rangle$ multiplied by $\lambda$ and $\mu$ has the same effect. Since $\lambda \not= \mu$, $\langle v,w\rangle$ has to be $0$.

Comment: arn't all linear maps representable by matrices once you pick a basis on a finite dimensional inner product space?

Comment: Yes, but if you *change* the basis then you *change* the matrix representation (except for scaling maps $T(v) = cv$, which are always represented by $cI_n$). Notions like adjoints and dual maps are basis-independent, but "transpose" requires a matrix representation. For example, if a linear map has a representation as a symmetric matrix (equal to its own transpose) in terms of one basis, it need not have a symmetric matrix representation in terms of another basis.